# Facebook Like-box

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-likebox

I am reading about how to style a Like-box that you get from Facebook. 
I have tried different solutions that have been linked here at Stack, ex: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/

It does seem that Facebook dosent allow you to style the like boxes however you like, or at all?
Are they blocking you for security ressons or is there a way, but i havent find it yet?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the options they give you there is no way to style it. I assume the do this for branding reasons.

The only way it can be done is by overwriting CSS given with the Like Box. However the article you link to is very old and they have most likely changed the CSS classes. They also may be implementing other things to stop you from doing it.

Besides the options they give you here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

You aren't meant to change anything else.